# CodenameOne iOS debug build error

Tags: codenameone

My iOS debug build fails. Here are some errors from the error.log file:

```
...
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.codename1.admob.AdMobManager.loadAd(AdMobManager.java:49)
at com.dd.midp.slicklottoca.SlickLottoCA.init(SlickLottoCA.java:177)
at com.dd.midp.slicklottoca.SlickLottoCAStub.run(SlickLottoCAStub.java:28)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1152)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:969)
at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
...
Error during processing: undefined method `path' for nil:NilClass
Backtrace:
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme/buildable_reference.rb:89:in `construct_buildable_name'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme/buildable_reference.rb:59:in `set_reference_target'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme/buildable_reference.rb:16:in `block in initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme/xml_element_wrapper.rb:53:in `create_xml_element_with_fallback'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme/buildable_reference.rb:14:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme/build_action.rb:96:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme/build_action.rb:96:in `block in initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme/xml_element_wrapper.rb:53:in `create_xml_element_with_fallback'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme/build_action.rb:77:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme.rb:186:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/scheme.rb:186:in `add_build_target'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:756:in `block in recreate_user_schemes'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:754:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.1.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:754:in `recreate_user_schemes'
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/hooks/fix_xcode_schemes.rb:5:in `<main>'
An error occurred recreating schemes, but the build still might work...
...
** ARCHIVE FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
CompileC build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SlickLottoCA/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/SlickLottoCA.build/Release-iphoneos/SlickLottoCA.build/Objects-normal/armv7/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.o SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
Failed xcodebuild step
```

The errors look to be related to the AdmobFullScreen cn1lib that I am using but it used to work and I didn't change anything related to this.

Comment: It looks like you removed a lot of lines from the full error log so I can't tell what went wrong.

Comment: Here is the link to the error log: https://codename-one.appspot.com/getData?m=result&i=5796355844079616&b=ea6f1526-5098-47c7-b2b3-a63b0255b31d&n=error.txt

Answer (score 0):

This is the error:

```
The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SlickLottoCA/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/SlickLottoCA.build/Release-iphoneos/SlickLottoCA.build/Objects-normal/armv7/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.o SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
Failed xcodebuild step
```

To understand it focus on this `com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.m` as that is the file that actually failed. To find the error search the log for `com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.m`:

```
CompileC build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SlickLottoCA/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/SlickLottoCA.build/Release-iphoneos/SlickLottoCA.build/Objects-normal/armv7/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.o SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O3 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DCOCOAPODS=1 -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.3.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -iquote /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SlickLottoCA/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/SlickLottoCA.build/Release-iphoneos/SlickLottoCA.build/SlickLottoCA-generated-files.hmap -I/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SlickLottoCA/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/SlickLottoCA.build/Release-iphoneos/SlickLottoCA.build/SlickLottoCA-own-target-headers.hmap -I/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SlickLottoCA/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/SlickLottoCA.build/Release-iphoneos/SlickLottoCA.build/SlickLottoCA-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SlickLottoCA/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/SlickLottoCA.build/Release-iphoneos/SlickLottoCA.build/SlickLottoCA-project-headers.hmap -I/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SlickLottoCA/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/include -I/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Firebase/Core/Sources -I/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Public -I/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase -I/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseAnalytics -I/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseCore -I/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseInstanceID -I/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Public/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK -I/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleInterchangeUtilities -I/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleSymbolUtilities -I/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleToolboxForMac -I/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SlickLottoCA/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/SlickLottoCA.build/Release-iphoneos/SlickLottoCA.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SlickLottoCA/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/SlickLottoCA.build/Release-iphoneos/SlickLottoCA.build/DerivedSources -F/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SlickLottoCA/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks -F/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks -F/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks/frameworks -F/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks -F/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks -F/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks -isystem /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Public -isystem /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase -isystem /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseAnalytics -isystem /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseCore -isystem /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseInstanceID -isystem /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Public/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK -isystem /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleInterchangeUtilities -isystem /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleSymbolUtilities -isystem /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleToolboxForMac -include /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SlickLottoCA/PrecompiledHeaders/SlickLottoCA-Prefix-bpywombausyhonckyloluumwxvap/SlickLottoCA-Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SlickLottoCA/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/SlickLottoCA.build/Release-iphoneos/SlickLottoCA.build/Objects-normal/armv7/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.d --serialize-diagnostics /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SlickLottoCA/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/SlickLottoCA.build/Release-iphoneos/SlickLottoCA.build/Objects-normal/armv7/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.dia -c /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.m -o /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/build/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/SlickLottoCA/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/SlickLottoCA.build/Release-iphoneos/SlickLottoCA.build/Objects-normal/armv7/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.o
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.m:2:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/CodenameOne_GLViewController.h:114:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GoogleMobileAds.h:23:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GADBannerView.h:13:
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GADInAppPurchaseDelegate.h:21:11: warning: duplicate protocol definition of 'GADDefaultInAppPurchaseDelegate' is ignored
@protocol GADDefaultInAppPurchaseDelegate<NSObject>
          ^
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.m:1:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.h:3:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/GADInterstitial.h:10:
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/GADInAppPurchaseDelegate.h:19:11: note: previous definition is here
@protocol GADDefaultInAppPurchaseDelegate<NSObject>
          ^
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.m:2:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/CodenameOne_GLViewController.h:114:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GoogleMobileAds.h:23:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GADBannerView.h:13:
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GADInAppPurchaseDelegate.h:40:11: warning: duplicate protocol definition of 'GADInAppPurchaseDelegate' is ignored
@protocol GADInAppPurchaseDelegate<NSObject>
          ^
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.m:1:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.h:3:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/GADInterstitial.h:10:
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/GADInAppPurchaseDelegate.h:38:11: note: previous definition is here
@protocol GADInAppPurchaseDelegate<NSObject>
          ^
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.m:2:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/CodenameOne_GLViewController.h:114:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GoogleMobileAds.h:23:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GADBannerView.h:14:
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GADRequest.h:20:28: warning: redefinition of typedef 'GADGender' is a C11 feature [-Wtypedef-redefinition]
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, GADGender) {
                           ^
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.m:1:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.h:3:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/GADInterstitial.h:13:
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/GADRequest.h:19:28: note: previous definition is here
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, GADGender) {
                           ^
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.m:2:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/CodenameOne_GLViewController.h:114:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GoogleMobileAds.h:23:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GADBannerView.h:14:
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GADRequest.h:20:28: error: redefinition of 'GADGender'
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, GADGender) {
                           ^
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.m:1:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.h:3:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/GADInterstitial.h:13:
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/GADRequest.h:19:28: note: previous definition is here
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, GADGender) {
                           ^
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.m:2:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/CodenameOne_GLViewController.h:114:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GoogleMobileAds.h:23:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GADBannerView.h:14:
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GADRequest.h:21:3: error: redefinition of enumerator 'kGADGenderUnknown'
  kGADGenderUnknown,  ///< Unknown gender.
  ^
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.m:1:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.h:3:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/GADInterstitial.h:13:
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/GADRequest.h:20:3: note: previous definition is here
  kGADGenderUnknown,  ///< Unknown gender.
  ^
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.m:2:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/CodenameOne_GLViewController.h:114:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GoogleMobileAds.h:23:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GADBannerView.h:14:
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GADRequest.h:22:3: error: redefinition of enumerator 'kGADGenderMale'
  kGADGenderMale,     ///< Male gender.
  ^
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.m:1:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.h:3:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/GADInterstitial.h:13:
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/GADRequest.h:21:3: note: previous definition is here
  kGADGenderMale,     ///< Male gender.
  ^
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.m:2:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/CodenameOne_GLViewController.h:114:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GoogleMobileAds.h:23:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GADBannerView.h:14:
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GADRequest.h:23:3: error: redefinition of enumerator 'kGADGenderFemale'
  kGADGenderFemale    ///< Female gender.
  ^
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.m:1:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.h:3:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/GADInterstitial.h:13:
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/GADRequest.h:22:3: note: previous definition is here
  kGADGenderFemale    ///< Female gender.
  ^
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.m:2:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/CodenameOne_GLViewController.h:114:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GoogleMobileAds.h:23:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GADBannerView.h:14:
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GADRequest.h:27:1: error: duplicate interface definition for class 'GADRequest'
@interface GADRequest : NSObject<NSCopying>
^
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.m:1:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.h:3:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/GADInterstitial.h:13:
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/GADRequest.h:26:12: note: previous definition is here
@interface GADRequest : NSObject<NSCopying>
           ^
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.m:2:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/CodenameOne_GLViewController.h:114:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GoogleMobileAds.h:23:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GADBannerView.h:14:
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GADRequest.h:57:51: error: property has a previous declaration
@property(nonatomic, copy, GAD_NULLABLE) NSArray *testDevices;
                                                  ^
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.m:1:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.h:3:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/GADInterstitial.h:13:
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/GADRequest.h:59:37: note: property declared here
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *testDevices;
                                    ^
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.m:2:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/CodenameOne_GLViewController.h:114:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GoogleMobileAds.h:23:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GADBannerView.h:14:
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GADRequest.h:62:40: error: property has a previous declaration
@property(nonatomic, assign) GADGender gender;
                                       ^
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.m:1:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.h:3:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/GADInterstitial.h:13:
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/GADRequest.h:64:40: note: property declared here
@property(nonatomic, assign) GADGender gender;
                                       ^
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.m:2:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/CodenameOne_GLViewController.h:114:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GoogleMobileAds.h:23:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GADBannerView.h:14:
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GADRequest.h:65:50: error: property has a previous declaration
@property(nonatomic, copy, GAD_NULLABLE) NSDate *birthday;
                                                 ^
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.m:1:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.h:3:
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/GADInterstitial.h:13:
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/GADRequest.h:67:38: note: property declared here
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSDate *birthday;
                                     ^
In file included from /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build7966420431196611238xxx/dist/SlickLottoCA-src/com_codename1_admob_AdMobNativeImpl.m:1:
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
4 warnings and 20 errors generated.
```

Snipped a bit since it was too long for SO...

The question is what did you do with admob that triggered this failure?

Did you add/change any build hints?

Comment: I didn't change any build hints. This start happening after 3.6 release and after updating my Netbeans to the latest plugin. Just to make sure the error has nothing to do with my code changes I sent a build for an older unchanged project that uses AdmobFullScreen cn1lib and it failed

Comment: What did you set in the past? It's possible that a former build hint/cn1lib that used to work collided with recent changes.

Comment: I set these build hints:
`ios.add_libs=AdSupport.framework;SystemConfiguration.framework;CoreTelephony.framework
ios.objC=true`

Comment: You might have older versions of libraries that conflict with this: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1790 I suggest removing all the `ios.*` build hints updating all the cn1libs and doing a refresh libs

Comment: I did what you suggested but still doesn't work. See error log: [link](https://codename-one.appspot.com/getData?m=result&i=6719963999240192&b=7837be8f-3d3d-4f03-8e70-c55b33a13d69&n=error.txt)

Comment: Are you sure you updated all the cn1libs before removing then refreshing? It looks like some of the stuff from an older library is still there.

Comment: Absolutely. It looks like there is an issue with the AdmobFullScreen cn1lib after the 3.6 release.

Comment: Can you file an issue on that? We'll try to reproduce it.

Comment: I filed issue #2016